# Brutal Legend: Do you get anything extra for completing everything?

Tags: achievements, brutal-legend

At the end of the game, Eddie Riggs says he'll be right back, he has stuff to do, and the game opens up again so you can finish things. I was wondering, if I bother to finished everything, will he say something different? (I know I'll get achievements for doing everything.)

No major spoilers, please!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just concept art, and a really excellent soundtrack of metal.

Comment: Bah. That blows! :(